# What is the error in this layout

Tags: android, android-layout

[image: I am having this error]

I am new to Android Development and I am having this layout problem in My Application. Need some help

Comment: This is an unsalvageable garbage statement that doesn't provide any value to stack overflow.  Please remove and repost when you have added a body to the message. edit: I see an answer, am I just not seeing a question on my browser?

Comment: just remove this line where you are getting error `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`

Comment: @Sparksis There is a screenshot of the IDE, perhaps the image did not render.

Comment: @MukeshKumar sorry about that.  I guess my companies websense is now blocking screenshots.  I tried to recant my downvote but it was too late.  :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to declare the `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` namespace once in your `Activity` which you have already done at the start of your layout. Remove the multiple namespace declarations of one which the error is being raised on.

The layout message is indicating just what it says. It's trying to tell you that your current hierarchical structure with regards to layout containers is redundant at some level.